# Node.js Express Can't get Post Data

Tags: node.js, express

When I post to /insertUser and it schema.saveUser(req) it doesn't find the correct data.  I am using node-inspector and it can't find my post data.  I have also tried req.body and it finds nothing.  I am sending a json

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var schema = require("./schemas");
var app = express();

app.get('/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World2');
});

app.post('/insertUser', function(req, res){
console.log("Request handler 'insertUser' was called.");
//console.log(req.body);

schema.saveUser(req);

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
res.send("You've sent the text: " + req);
response.write("The following data has been saved to the database: " + jsonString);
res.end();
});

var server = app.listen(8888, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});



function saveUser(postData){
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(postData);

  var newUser = new User({
    name: jsonObj.name,
     email: jsonObj.email,
    photoURL: jsonObj.photourl,
    groups: jsonObj.groups
  });

  newUser.save(function(err, newUser) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(newUser);
  });
}
```

edit:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

     at Object.parse (native)
     at Object.saveUser (schemas.js:42:22)
    at Object.handle (server.js:25:9)
    at next_layer (route.js:103:13)
     at Route.dispatch (route.js:107:5)
     at c (index.js:195:24)
    at Function.proto.process_params (index.js:251:12)
     at next (index.js:189:19)
     at next (index.js:166:38)
    at Layer.urlencodedParser [as handle] (index.js:70:44)
```

Comment: what is your middleware config ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that is?

Comment: `app.use(express.router)` and that stuff

Comment: I don't have any of that

Comment: Most likely the problem is on the client side. How are you posting to your server?

Comment: Right now I am trying to post a json from POSTMAN on chrome.  However I will be using it with an android application.  If I don't use express I am able to post fine.

Comment: It doens't look like that problem is express

Comment: @CamSonaris so your code is full there ? what is your express version (npm ls express)

Comment: when I use the debugger it isn't even getting a request

Comment: I am using express@4.0.0 and the code is fully there

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: see my edit on the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in Express 4 you need to use `router` object instead of `app` to define the routes... Something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var schema = require("./schemas");
var app = express();

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World2');
});

router.post('/insertUser', function(req, res){
console.log("Request handler 'insertUser' was called.");
});
...
```

Answer (score 3):

**In the client**

`Cannot GET /insertUser` means this is a GET route which is called by the browser  when clicking on a link or entering the page URL.

But you specified `app.post('/insertUser'...` which means that the route will be called only when using the POST method (used when submitting forms for instance, NEVER when clicking on links)

If this is the result of a form, don't forget to specify the method (`<form method="post">`). Same for ajax calls.

If you want to test in dev mode you can use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) on chrome to easily call POST routes. If you don't have chrome use curl.

**Back-end**

Express body parser isn't included in express 4.0 so you need to install it then use it:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var schema = require("./schemas");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World2');
});
```

Then you can use `req.body`